# Transparent HTTP tunnel to TCP

Tags: http, tcp, tunnel, http-tunneling

I want to open any arbitrary TCP socket on a server, but it's behind a proxy and I can only use a port that is intended for HTTP hosting only. Simply put, what is the most transparent way to wrap such a socket into an HTTP connection? Preferably I would call a *nix program through a shell script in the server that would take care of translating the requests.

I apologize if this was answered before, but I am struggling to find and understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with [Chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel), which provides a single binary for both servers and clients, with features like authentication and reverse port forwarding. For instance:

```
chisel server
```

will run an HTTP server in `$PORT` or 8080, and

```
chisel client server.com 4567:123
```

connects to `server.com` and maps the remote port 123 into the local port 4567.

Other solutions are still welcome, particularly if they involve more transparency, frequently preinstalled tools like `netcat`, and if they also provide support for other protocols like UDP.